# How to firebullet continually

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm learning Swift and SpriteKit with a little game, in which the player has to defend a military base. However, the player has to touch for fire a bullet. 
But I would like that when he touches the screen that the fire is continual, and not to tap the screen everytime for one bullet.
Furthermore when he stopped to touch the screen, the firebullet stop.

My firebullet function :

```
func fireBullet () {
    let bullet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bullet")
    bullet.name = "Bullet" //afin de permettre l'arrêt des missiles en cas de gameOver
    bullet.setScale(0.5)
    bullet.position = CGPoint(x: planet.position.x, y: planet.position.y)
    bullet.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    bullet.zPosition = 1
    bullet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: bullet.size) // changer le rectangle en forme circulaire
    bullet.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    bullet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = physicsCategories.bullet
    bullet.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = physicsCategories.none
    bullet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = physicsCategories.asteroid
    self.addChild(bullet)
    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1.0)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([bulletSound, moveBullet, deleteBullet])
    bullet.run(bulletSequence)
}
```

And I call it in the TouchesBegan :

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if currentGameState == gameState.preGame {
        gameStart()
    }
   else if currentGameState == gameState.inGame {
        fireBullet()
    }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could call fireAction inside itself with a SKAction.

```
func fireBullet() {

    ...

    let moveBullet = SKAction.moveTo(y: self.size.height + bullet.size.height, duration: 1.0)
    let deleteBullet = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let fireCooldown = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5)
    let bulletSequence = SKAction.sequence([bulletSound, moveBullet, deleteBullet, fireCooldown])
    bullet.run(bulletSequence) {
        if currentGameState == gameState.inGame, isTouchingScreen {
            fireBullet()
        }
        // runs actions, wait for 0.5 seconds and trigger a new fireBullet in completion
    }
}
```

For cooldown adjustments you can change fireCooldown value or if you don't want to wait for the whole action to happen you can remove fireCooldown from the sequence and trigger it alone with the completion. 
IsTouchingScreen are a boolean that you can set to true inside touchesBegan and then to false in touchesEnded.

Comment: this will not work, it requires you rub your finger on the button constantly

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by running it inside the `update` method, checking a wait time of your choice, and calling the fire bullet if both time and isTouching are meet.

Something like this (not tested, writing from memory) firing every 1.5 seconds

```
var isTouching = false
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    fireBall()
    isTouching = true
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    isTouching = false
    dt = 0
}

var lastUpdateTime: TimeInterval = 0
var dt: TimeInterval = 0

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    //Update time fraction per frame
    if lastUpdateTime > 0 {
        dt += currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    } else {
        dt = 0
    }
    if dt > 1.5 && isTouching {
        fireBall()
        dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime
}
```

Also another **important thing** is: remove the node when is no longer need, you can do it using an delay as end of sequence SKAction (wait x seconds) and then the SKAction.removeFromParent.

Comment: If you exit the app and comeback, this may cause potential issues like a bullet firing prematurely

Comment: Well, that is why it should be a pause state management, not only with this. Also reset dt along with the touch ended.

Comment: you may want to explain that in your answer so that the OP does not come back 3 months from now when hitting that bug.  Your code also does not cover things like when the game is lagging or other such potential issues that will cause your dt to become 1.5 when ingame time 1.5 seconds (or even 3 seconds) have happened.  There are also other issues like what if your dt is 1.6, then 1.5, then 1.7.  Your fireballs are firing at inconsistent times, which again may not be desired depending on how important the repetative timing is.  You may want to address those flaws as well.

Comment: If your dt is that long you may have other serious issues within the update cycle. I do not go further because I have zero clue about future game mechanism, also maybe using moveto is not the right way to do it. You are free to write an answer too! 

Comment: Already placed an answer, and it is not a serious issue, these are every day issues that you will encounter.  Something as simple as a “You have  20% battery remaining” notification could pop up, causing your game to lag just enough to throw off your game timing.

Comment: Sorry did not see it. Looks correct! And regarding fighting the update cycle, yeah there are things to take care about. I've not used SK recently and so seing SKAction loop to manage this is weird to me because I remember that I found more issues in the end than follow the delta way time.

Comment: There is nothing”wrong” with delta time, you just need to handle it properly, which is why I am giving you a “hard” time with it (In the end it is about making great answers that won’t bring users back 6 months from now)

Answer (score 0):

To fire continuosly,  all you need to do is simply create a series of actions that will repeat when you enter the touch began state, and stop the actions when you release touch

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if currentGameState == gameState.preGame {
        gameStart()
    }
    else if currentGameState == gameState.inGame {

        let fire = SKAction.run{self.fireBullet()}
        let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration:0.1)  //delay between shots
        let seq = SKAction.sequence([fire,wait])
        let repeat = SKAction.repeatForever(seq)
        planet.run(repeat, withKey:"bullets")
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if currentGameState == gameState.preGame {

    }
    else if currentGameState == gameState.inGame {
        planet.removeAction(forKey:"bullets")
    }
}
```

Now you are going to need to handle the removal of the action when the touch is cancelled. You are also going to need to handle when multiple fingers are pressiing the screen, because you do not want to have your action restart when it happens.

As a side note, I would recommend creating a good chunk of bullets in the beginning of your app, and just keep recycling them to avoid constantly making new bullets.